# How to calculate the $x$-component of the angular momentum $L_x$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

I am considering the hydrogen atom. Given $L_z$ and each of the $n,\ell,m$ values, is there a way to calculate $L_x$? In the same way that $L_z=\hbar m$ is there a similar expression for $L_x$?

Comment: Perhaps you could expand a little. What do you mean 'given $L_z$' for instance?

Comment: I mean that suppose we have measured Lz to be ℏ, and we have measured the energy to be a certain number of eV, and we know the values of the quantum numbers n,l and m, how do we calculate Lx?

Comment: By saying that we have measured $L_z$ to be $\hbar$, you've already specified $m = 1$. Similarly, if we've measured the energy to be a certain number of eV, then the quantum number $n$ is also determined. Just to check that you appreciate that the numbers $n$, $m$ and $l$ are the very numbers that _characterise_ the amount of energy and angular momentum, and can't be chosen independently of the amount of energy and angular momentum? (PS --- are you asking this question in the context of the hydrogen atom?)

Comment: Yes I am considering hydrogen here sorry should have made that clear! I understand that n,m and l characterise the energy and angular momentum, for example E=-13.6/n^2 for hydrogen and in so knowing n you know the energy. My question is how do we then calculate Lx? Is there an expression for Lx in terms of these principal quantum numbers?

Comment: Short answer: no. Let me write up an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no: no, there isn't a way to calculate $L_x$. Let me expand.

You may be aware of the uncertainty relation between position and momentum, which can be written like this

$$ \langle [ \hat{x}, \hat{p}_x ] \rangle \geq i \hbar $$

What this means is that it's impossible to know precisely both the position and the momentum of a particle at a given point in time. If your particle is in some state for which the position is known very precisely, then the momentum of the particle must be very uncertain. That is to say, the particle doesn't *have* a precise, definite momentum --- the best we can do is talk about its average momentum and uncertainties in its momentum.

It turns out that there's a very similar relation for angular momentum, which looks like this

$$ \langle [ \hat{L}_x, \hat{L}_y ] \rangle \geq i \hbar \langle \hat{L}_z \rangle $$

Here (as before) the angle brackets denote 'expectation value' and the square brackets denote the commutator. What this is saying, essentially, is that for any system which has a non-zero z-component of angular momentum (for example, our hydrogen atom in the state $m = 1$), the quantities $L_x$ and $L_y$ are intrinsically uncertain. The system simply doesn't *have* a definite x- or y-component of angular momentum.

Note that the quantum number $m$ *means* the z-component of angular momentum (in units of $\hbar$). So the 'formula' for getting from the quantum number $m$ to the z-component of angular momentum --- namely, $L_z = m\hbar$ --- isn't really a formula at all, it's basically just a definition.

As such, there's simply no way that we could write $L_x$ or $L_y$ in terms of $m$, in the same way that if you gave me a randomly shaped box and told me its height $h$, there's simply no way I would be able to write the *width* in terms of it. The height of the box doesn't tell me anything about the width.

However, because of what I've argued above, we can actually make a stronger statement than just 'you can't write $L_x$ in terms of $m$'. The stronger statement is that we couldn't even *find* a number that characterised the x-component of angular momentum, because for so long as we know the z-component, the x- and y- components are uncertain. Hope this helps!

Comment: ok so if there isn't a definite value for Lx, is there a range of potential, discrete values that it COULD be, given Lz, or is it completely independent, as in your box analogy?

Comment: Actually yes, there are a range of potential, discrete values $L_x$ could be, given $L_z$. The details require some understanding of operator methods in quantum mechanics, and are not totally straightforward. For instance, if you're in a state with $l = 1$, $m = 1$ (i.e. the z-component of angular momentum being $\hbar$) then there is a 25% chance of finding $L_x = \hbar$, a 25% chance of finding $L_x = -\hbar$ and a 50% chance of finding $L_x = 0$. If instead you were in a state with $l = 1$, $m = 0$ then there is a 50% chance of finding $L_x = \pm\hbar$ and 0% chance of finding $L_x = 0$.